# Sequelize - Is there a way to insert associations in queryInterface.bulkInsert?

Tags: sequelize.js

Working with [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/), I am creating data with my migrations. However, on Many-to-Many relations, I can't create data in other entities associated with the one I'm migrating.

```
queryInterface.bulkInsert("Pages", [
      {
        name: "Home",
        title: "Website Homepage",
        metaDescription: "Welcome on this website",
        pageType: "generic",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
      {
        name: "Menu",
        title: "The Menu of the week",
        metaDescription:
          "Here is the menu of the week.",
        pageType: "specific",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
    ]);
```

I have a `Page` and a `Restaurant` entity that have a `Many To Many` relation. I would like to create an entry in DB for my menu Page to be linked to Restaurant. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To create these, I used my migration with the Many-to-Many table, and created a bulkInsert there too, looking like this :

```
        queryInterface.bulkInsert("restaurantpages", [
      {
        idPage: 1,
        idRestaurant: 1,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      }
```